# io:fread for unicode characters does not work with -noshell

Tags: erlang

I am trying to read unicode characters (beyond latin1 range) with `io:fread`.

The code below works fine in shell mode:

```
Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G) 

1> io:fread("Input some Unicode characters: ", "~ts").

Input some Unicode characters: 呵呵

{ok,[[21621,21621]]}
```

When using the `-noshell` flag, however, it returns another list:

```
$ erl -noshell -eval "io:format(\"~p\", [io:fread(\"Input: \", \"~ts\")])."

Input: 呵呵

{ok,[[229,145,181,229,145,181]]}
```

Does anyone know why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From erlang [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html),

> When Erlang is started with -oldshell or -noshell, the I/O-server for
>   standard_io is default set to bytewise encoding, while an interactive
>   shell defaults to what the environment variables says
>
> With the io:setopts/2 function you can set the encoding of a file or
>   other I/O-server...

Therefore, `io:setopts/2` should be added as follow;

```
$ erl -noshell -eval "io:setopts(standard_io, [{encoding, unicode}]), io:format(\"~p\", [io:fread(\"Input: \", \"~ts\")])."
Input: 呵呵
{ok,[[21621,21621]]}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. The input is right now, but after I set the encoding option to unicode (or utf8), the output becomes messy characters. Do you have any clue about it ?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any other solution but bit syntax seems to solve the problem. `erl -noshell -eval "io:setopts([{encoding,utf8}]), io:format(\"~ts~n\", [<<\"Hello world 呵呵\">>])."`

Comment: I have found out the problem. I am using Erlang R16, although it can compile utf-8 source files, it still regards all string literals as latin1 encoding. A comments "%% -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" must be added to the source file, then utf-8 string literals can be used. In R17 the default encoding has changed to utf-8.